# Difficulty understanding optional parentheses

Tags: ruby

I am having problem understanding the execution in the following code snippet.

```
x = 5
puts (0..10).include?(x) ? "yes" : "no"
```

It is giving the desired output which is `yes`. But when I am omitting the parentheses of `include?`
method like this :

```
x = 5
puts (0..10).include? x ? "yes" : "no"
```

then output is `false`.
I am using `ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because in the second case ruby takes the result of the whole `x ? "yes" : "no"` expresion as argument.

```
 puts (0..10).include? x ? "yes" : "no"
```

is equivalent to:

```
 puts (0..10).include?(x ? "yes" : "no")
```

Ruby allows to omit brackets for method calls, but there are cases, when it's impossible to omit them to write what you've intended.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like this...

```
puts (0..10).include? x ? "yes" : "no"
```

is the same as...

```
puts ((0..10).include? (x ? "yes" : "no"))
```

which is the same as...

```
puts ((0..10).include? ("yes"))
```

which is the same as...

```
puts (false) #=> false
```